# Make changes in multiple files in a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-os

I have 100s of files having text. The text format is like, on each line, there is a new sentence. Like below

```
Include details about your goal
Describe expected and actual results
Include any error messages
```

Now I have created a function that makes the changes in the above sentences and the input of the function is the sentence. Like,

```
masked_text('Include details about your goal')
```

Now, I want to implement this function to each file's sentences with the for loop.
I wrote this code, but that

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
files = os.listdir("/path/to/directory/")
for sentence_file in tqdm(files):
    with open("/path/to/directory/"+sentence_file) as f_input:
        text = f_input.read()
        new_text = masked_text(text)
        with open('/new/dir/path/' + sentence_file,'w') as f_output:
            f_output.write(new_text)
            f_output.close()
```

But this code, gives the output in a form of a single sentence. Like below,

```
Include details about your goal Describe expected and actual results Include any error messages
```

I tried as below, but this will give me a single sentence as output for each file. So not useful.

```
for sentence_file in tqdm(files):
    with open("/path/to/directory/"+sentence_file,'r') as f_input:
        for line in f_input:
            new_text = masked_text(line)
            with open('/new/dir/path/'+sentence_file,'w') as f_output:
                f_output.write(new_text)
                f_output.close()
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to include `"\n"` at the end of each line

Comment: Hello, try to put your sentence in a var in you for loop and reset it each time

Comment: @vks Sorrry, I can not. The texts files have sentences in 400k numbers

Comment: @AdityaParikh add it to your `masked_text` function